# For a finite Abelian group $A$, $\mathbb Q \otimes_{\mathbb Z} A =0.$

Tags: tensor-products

Can someone please let me know that how $(\frac{1}{3}) \otimes (5 \bmod 7) = 0 $ in $\mathbb Q \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z_7$?

Can we do like as follows?

$$(\frac{1}{3}) \otimes (5 \bmod 7) = (\frac{7}{21}) \otimes (5 \bmod 7)=  (\frac{1}{21}) \otimes 7(5 \bmod 7) = (\frac{1}{21}) \otimes 0=0.$$
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @fredgoodman Many thanks!